# .htaccess rewrite rule appends www to IP address - how to avoid?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My htaccess rewrite rule appends www to my ip, so when i type in my browser

`1.1.1.1`

it automatically becomes

`www.1.1.1.1` and doesn't load.

How do I avoid that but keep appending `www` to `domain.com` type of requests?

The original rule:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^www\.|1\.1\.1\.1)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or for all IP addresses:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^www\.|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! this won't break the other redirections I have?

Comment: I do not think so. Because it concerns only the domain name.

Comment: do you know - if i want to also add localhost to that RewriteCond rule, do i just add it after `www\.` like this: `^www\.|^localhost|\d+\.`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    # force non-www domain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This may be another solution.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```